# Orbit-Stabilizer theorem for continuous groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, semigroups-and-monoids

The orbit-stabilizer relationship (also known as the orbit-stabilizer theorem) is very clear for finite groups. Is there an equivalent relation for continuous groups? 
Also, is there a similar notion for monoid (or semigroup) actions on vector spaces?

Comment: You need a condition on the action.  For example, an action of the integers on the circle by irrational rotations has trivial stabilizers, but the orbit of a point is not discrete.

Comment: Orbit-stabilizer doesn't really work nicely for monoids and semigroups because of irreversibility.

Comment: Any reference reading on this? Somehow, I couldn't spot anything concrete via google; but I suspect quite a lot must have been studied (may be much less than the case of groups).